# Retrieving names of modules included in a cabal package from parsing the .cabal file

Tags: haskell, cabal

I wonder if there is a way to retrieve the module names of a cabal package from parsing the .cabal files.

I have tried to use parsePackageDescription from Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse but for instance when I try parsing the .cabal of the Cabal package itself (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.18.1.2/Cabal.cabal) the library value of PackageDescription is Nothing even though there is a library section with both exposed-modules and other.modules in the .cabal file.

Is this intended or am I doing anything wrong? Also, if it is intended, does anyone know any other simple way of retrieving the modules names?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Cabal are you using? I just tried and had no problems parsing Cabal's own .cabal file using Cabal 1.18.1.2, including the library section. Can you walk us through what exactly you did?

Comment: I am using ghc 7.6.3 with Cabal 1.18.1. I read the Cabal file and then run parsePackageDescription on the result of the read. The parsing works somewhat fine as several fields like author and description gets filled in. However, the library section parses to Nothing for me.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the problem is. When you parse a package using `parsePackageDescription`, you get a value of type `GenericPackageDescription`. In order to get the final PackageDescription, you need to run the `flattenPackageDescription` function from the `Distribution.PackageDescription.Configuration`. This final package description should contain the library information.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick. I thought that I should get the same result by extracting the `PackageDescription` value of `GenericPackageDescription` and did not know about the the `flattenPackageDescription` function.