# How to import rather than load modules on startup with 'stack ghci'?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I have a haskell package called `prime-tools`. When I use `stack ghci` inside the package directory, I expect it to open up an interactive `ghci` and automatically `import prime-tools`. Instead, I find that it **loads all of the modules** declared in the .cabal file.

For example, here is the extract from my .cabal file showing which modules are declared:

```
library
  -- Modules exported by the library.
  exposed-modules:     PrimeTools.MathStuff, PrimeTools.Factors, PrimeTools.PQTrials, PrimeTools.Main, PrimeTools.Base, PrimeTools.Lucas

  -- Modules included in this library but not exported.
  other-modules:       PrimeTools.Extras
```

And this is what happens as I receive the `ghci>` prompt after running `stack ghci` in the project folder:

```
Ok, modules loaded: PrimeTools.MathStuff, PrimeTools.Factors, PrimeTools.PQTrials, PrimeTools.Main, PrimeTools.Base, PrimeTools.Lucas, PrimeTools.Extras.
ghci>
```

The problem with *loading the modules* instead of `import prime-tools` is that I can now use all functions defined in all modules **whether or not they are exported**.

An example of the issues arising from this distinction: there are two modules in package `prime-tools` which have implementations of a function called `pfactor`. One of them is exported, and intended to be used by the end user of the package, while the other is for internal use only and not exported.

*Before someone comments, there is good reason to have two implementations of `pfactor`, but it's not relevant to my question.*

---

My question: how can I use `stack` to automatically start up a `ghci` environment with the local version of `ghc` and **import** the package whose folder I run the command in?

My desired behaviour would be equivalent to running the following sequence of commands:

```
stack ghci
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.MathStuff
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.Factors
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.PQTrials
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.Main
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.Base
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.Lucas
ghci> :module -PrimeTools.Extras
ghci> import PrimeTools.MathStuff
ghci> import PrimeTools.Factors
ghci> import PrimeTools.PQTrials
ghci> import PrimeTools.Main
ghci> import PrimeTools.Base
ghci> import PrimeTools.Lucas
```

The key here is that I want to import the *exposed-modules* declared in the .cabal file and **not to *load* any modules**. I don't mind if the *other-modules* are also imported, though. Is there a way I can do this using `stack` without having to run this long sequence of commands every time?

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable workaround is defining [a custom GHCi macro](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:def) for importing your modules the way you want it. Create a `.ghci` file in your project root along these lines:

```
:{
:def deload (\_ -> return 
    ":module -PrimeTools.MathStuff\n\
    \import PrimeTools.MathStuff"
    )
:}
```

With this, the `:deload` command in GHCi  will remove from scope and then re-import `PrimeTools.MathStuff` -- you can add as many modules as you want to the list. Though I have written this using [multiline string syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22918837/2751851), you can have any `String -> IO String` expression within the parentheses, so feel free to spell or extend it however you see fit.

Comment: Using `:load PrimeTools.Base` brings in definitions that are not exported. This has always been my experience, having used `:load` with several other modules in the past.

Comment: The link you provided says this: ":load Main.hs ... Everything that is in scope at the top-level in the module Main we just loaded is also in scope at the prompt", and like Myridium that is indeed also my experience.

Comment: Also, when I run `stack ghci --no-load`, I'm unable to import the package. I'm told it's hidden: `It is a member of the hidden package ‘prime-tools-0.1.2.0@prime_EA4ezNOr21Z4zu3ZQR52et’.`

Comment: @jlmg and Myridium -- Seems I mixed up the multiple uses and meanings of `*` in this context; I have removed that final paragraph until I figure out how to phrase that better. Note that part of the reason I wrote that is that, in spite of the other issues, you do want have the modules loaded, as otherwise they won't be found, leading to the issue Myridium describes in the other comment.

Comment: @Myridium Before importing, you need to load the source file with e.g. `:load src/PrimeTools/MathStuff.hs`. Between this and my other misunderstanding, that defeats the point of `--no-load` for your purposes, so I have removed that paragraph as well.

Comment: @duplode - Running `:load ./src/PrimeTools/Base` or `:load PrimeTools.Base` loads the methods that are not exported, too. That's why I don't want to load the modules. As far as I've experienced, *loading* a module always includes importing *all* definitions, even those that are not exported, whereas **importing** only takes in those that are exported.

Comment: After a quick test, running `:module PrimeTools.Base` seems to take in only those definitions which are exported.

Comment: @Myridium On `:load ./src/PrimeTools/Base`: indeed -- that's what I meant with my previous comment, once I realised I mixed things up with respect to `:load`. As for `:module PrimeTools.Base`, it is indeed equivalent to `import PrimeTools.Base` (as opposed to `:module *PrimeTools.Base`, which will do what you don't want).

Comment: Okay. Though this solution does help remove some of the tedium, I don't like the hard-coded strings for the module names. Is there some way to have it automatically read the `.cabal` file for modules to unload and reimport?

Comment: @Myridium Since the command definition is arbitrary Haskell, in principle it should be possible to parse the .cabal file and extract the module names, even using the Cabal library to do so (cf. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22785670/2751851)) as long as you import it at the beginning of the `.ghci` file. (I only say "in principle" because I haven't tried it yet.)

Comment: Alright, that's too much trouble for me to worry about. It seems odd to me that `stack ghci` doesn't already behave the way I would expect, so I thought there might be some simple way to do this with `stack` flags or something.

Comment: @Myridium Actually, I think it makes more sense the way it currently works. For most cases, there is no point in restricting what the developer should see. Putting everything in scope ensures the developer can get right to work without having to bring things into scope. Your problem right now was because you had a naming conflict between what's exported and what's not, but that could've just as easily happened between the exports of different modules. Anyway, it's often quicker to type qualified names to avoid ambiguities than to bring multiple things into scope on your own.